# Scheme implementation with multicore implementation of SRFI-18?

Tags: concurrency, scheme, multicore

I'll be working on a project in concurrent programming, and it would be nice to be able to use Scheme. However, for this project it will be *really* necessary to use different CPU cores (continuation-based threads won't do).

So, is there some R5RS Scheme that implements SRFI-18 making use of different CPU cores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Guile 2.0](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) has a [SRFI 18 implementation](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/SRFI_002d18.html) that uses POSIX threads. (Guile 1.8 had POSIX threads, but no SRFI 18.)

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never:

[bigloo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigloo) [supports srfi-18](https://www-sop.inria.fr/indes/fp/Bigloo/bigloo-1.html#Features) and [POSIX-threads](https://www-sop.inria.fr/indes/fp/Bigloo/doc/bigloo-18.html#Posix-Threads)

Answer (score 0):

[Chicken Scheme](http://www.call-cc.org) compiles to C and [supports SRFI-18](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Unit%20srfi-18) (although you should read the notes section!).

Comment: Thanks -- but as far as I understand it won't generate code that uses multiple cores, right?

Comment: that's is true, Chicken's thread model uses [green threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%20threads)